# Securely passing login token from one website to another in a shared database

Tags: security, https, single-sign-on, token

I have two websites on different servers and I need to permit single sign on from one site to the other. Both websites have access to the same database. Users are already authenticated and trusted on website A, but I'd like for them to click a link and automatically get logged into and redirected to website B. I have looked into SAML and other SSO options, but because both sites can access the same database, I'm wondering if I can use a simple token to permit SSO?

The setup is:

`www.websiteA.com > databaseA`

`www.websiteB.com > databaseA`

I was thinking something along the lines of:

- `www.websiteA.com/sso.php`

  - Create a random token record in databaseA associated with that user, let's say ABCD1234
- Redirect to `www.websiteB.com/login.php?token=ABCD1234`

  - Check databaseA for that token, and log the associated user in

Is this a secure way of performing single sign on between these two websites? Is a URL variable secure if it is performed over HTTPS and if the token is only destroyed after it's use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea of generating a token on site A and passing it to site B as a means of authentication can I think be acceptable in many cases. It is not fundamentally flawed, while as you mentioned, the best practice is doing it in a standard way like for example OAuth2 (OpenID Connect for identities).

However, as always, details matter a lot.

The token needs to be generated securely (based on a cryptographically secure random generator), needs to have enough entropy (~ long enough), it needs to be transmitted securely, stored on the client securely (if at all, but it will always be stored in memory at least), verification on the receiver end should not be vulnerable to a race condition (attacker and victim send token at the same time, two threads on the server both check if token is valid, both find it is, then both invalidate it, but that doesn't matter, token was valid for both of them), etc.

The only real weakness security-wise in your question, that I think makes your proposed solution directly vulnerable is passing the token in the URL. HTTPS does protect against an eavesdropping attacker, but a url parameter may get logged on intermediate proxies (a corporate user for instance may not even be aware of such proxies, and those terminate SSL many times, exploiting corporate certificates being trusted on clients), it may be remembered in the client browser, may get logged on the target server, etc. If the token is only valid until its first use, that mitigates the risk somewhat, but it would be best to send it in the request body (POST) instead of a url parameter.